# Установка Windows 7 на виртуальную машину

Tags: windows, windows-7, установка, виртуальная-машина

Обращение к системным администраторам. Помогите установить Windows 7 на virtual box. Скачал ISO образ системы пытаюсь запустить установщик, ничего не выходит, вот скриншоты

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что именно не выходит?

Comment: @insolor запустить установщик

Comment: Создаете пустую машину с жестким диском, запускаете. При первом запуске предлагает примонтировать установочный диск. Выбираете диск. Дальше диск должен запуститься (если он установочный).

Comment: Оперативы скока дал?

Comment: @donRumata 2 гигабайта

Comment: @insolor Так и делаю в этом то и проблема

Comment: Iso оригинальный?

Comment: @donRumata Нет, конечно. Но это никогда не мешало устанавливать ОС на реальные компьютеры. Нужна именно лицензия?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, я однажды видел, как человек тупо скомпоновал файлы в образ диска, обычного, не загрузочного, и пытался установить с этого образа систему на виртуалку. Надеюсь у вас не такой случай?

Comment: @insolor Запускал этот ISO на своей системе. Он работал

Comment: Что значит "он работал"? Файлы открывались или вы записали образ на диск или флешку и установка стартовала при старте компа?

Comment: @insolor Вошел в ISO запустил setup все запустилось, нажал кнопку "установить", стартовала установка

Comment: @insolor Я даже пробовал добавить в виртуальную машину ISO ubuntu, но установка linux тоже не стартовала.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, то что при запуске setup запустилась установка еще не говорит о том, что диск будет стартовать при запуске компьютера. Для этого он должен быть bootable ("стартующим"). Еще предположение, проверьте в настройках машины, чтобы в порядке загрузки оптический диск был выше жесткого диска: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNAfm.png

Comment: @insolor, а дать ссылку на "стартующий" диск Вы можете?

Comment: @Konstantin_SH, любой iso с дистрибутивом linux скачанный с официального сайта дистрибутива будет стартующим, например. Для проверки можно скачать образ slitaz, он около 50 Мб, проверить на нем. Вообще, где-то я видел образы жестких дисков с установленной Windows7, вроде как даже выкладываемые самими Microsoft, для каких-то тестовых целей (но скорее всего не активированные).

Comment: "Нужна именно лицензия?" нет, но раз у тебя что-то не пашет - очень может быть, что репак от вася-пупкин-орг - не самое лучшее решение в качестве эталона. На всякий случай: 6aafbbffc12bb63894932210d5bcb69773b46c98 - sha1 оригинальной 64-bit семёрки.

Comment: "но установка linux тоже не стартовала" а вот это уже интереснее. Проц amd или intel?

Comment: @donRumata intel core i5

Comment: `VT-x`, `VT-d` включены?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в ISO. Скачал другой, предварительно проверив по sha1, все заработало, вот скриншот. Всем спасибо за помощь. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А вот если бы вы покупали лицензионную версию Windows у Microsoft, то проблем не возникло бы

Comment: @andreymal Я студент, у меня нет денег на лицензию. У многих тоже, я думаю, а Education Программ у Microsoft нет.

Comment: А я же говорил!

Comment: @andreymal, как наличие "кассового\товарного" чека убережёт от битого исошника?

Comment: @donRumata так, что в майкрософте кривой исошник очень вряд ли сделают, а при доставке исошника до пользователя биться там нечему (в 2019 году живём всё-таки)

Comment: @andreymal, живёшь в крупном городе? У кучи народу до сих пор adsl по полусгнившим проводам и расшаренный 3g через смарт, который ловит, если его закинуть на шкаф. Я живу в миллионнике, но буквально в 30 км от города - 2мбит на вход - счастье. Есть чему биться, поверь.

Comment: @donRumata в протоколе TCP вот уж почти полвека встроены контрольные суммы для автоматической проверки передаваемых данных. Хоть adsl, хоть диалап — значения не имеет.