# Установка Windows 7 на VirtualBox

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualbox

Мне сделали загрузочную флешку, хочу её попробовать, а загрузиться с неё не могу.
Виртуалка её видит, все, но при перезагрузке виртуалки буквы для выбора флешки нет и все тут!

У меня там неактивно:

[image: Снимок]

*Добавлено:* дошел я, короче, с флешкой вот до чего:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никто не знает, что с этим делать?

Comment: 1)Настройки и выбераеш с чего начинать загруску

Comment: VirtualBox не поддерживает загрузку с USB

Comment: Не совсем понятны данные действия, зачем? Скачай образ, далее создай Windows-машину (не забудь указать правильную битность, 32 или 64), вставь образ на место диска и все ок, загрузка и установка понеслась.

Comment: Да не хочу я качать что попало и откуда попало. Мне тот человек, который сделал флешку, до этого сам систему устанавливал и все было ОК.

Comment: Ну, и что? Изготовил я, наконец-то файл `.vmdk`, подключил его к виртуалке в качестве диска, а виртуалка с него не загружается. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @Grek79 пока нам неизвестно, что и как вы там изготовили, мы помочь не сможем. А загружаться с USB виртуалбокс как два дня назад не умел, так и сегодня не умеет

Comment: @Grek79 и не надо качать откуда попало, для Windows есть официальный сайт Microsoft, для Linux-дистрибутивов соответственно свои сайты под каждый. Если это, откуда попало, то мне страшно предположить что за образ у тебя в руках.

Comment: Цифровая подпись не совпадает, вот и проверенный образ от знакомого или откуда там...

Comment: А что делать? рр

Comment: Сначала я делал, [как сказано здесь](https://remontcompa.ru/page,1,3,446-zagruzka-c-usb-v-virtualbox.html). При этом при загрузке виртуалки в *AHCI controller* появилась цифра 2, но нажатие ее во время загрузки виртуалки ничего не дало. И виртуалка не видела флешку. Поэтому я обратился к ютубу. Я так рассудил, что сначала мне нужно подключить установочную флешку к виртуалке. [Вот это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l41-wWvXXKk) решило эту проблему. В Настройки > USB я поставил галочку в *Включить контроллер USB*, при этом переключатель установил в положение *Контроллер USB 2.0 (EHCI),

Comment: снял галочку с загрузочной флешки (при этом из *фильтры устройств USB* я ее не удалял). Не помогло. Опять пошел на Ютьюб. [Вот в этом видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fopjnpoIAzk&t=403s) узнал, что созданному файлу .vdmk нужно назначить нулевой порт. Назначил.

Comment: Ну, помогите, плиз, неужели никто здесь с таким не сталкивался? Я же выкладываю (пытаюсь выкладывать) свои знания.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/942584/943445#comment1568871_942584 - тут контрольная сумма win7-msdn. Гуглишь, качаешь торрентом, ставишь, наслаждаешься работой.

Comment: L.F.C., у меня нет ключа активации какой-либо Винды. Нашел [вот это](http://tavalik.ru/zagruzka-s-fleshki-v-virtualnyx-mashinax/). Все равно не запускается с флешки. Может, файл .iso не подходит к моей версии виртуалбокса? Хотя заставка с выбором вариантов загрузки и звездами появляется.

Answer (score -1):

Далее нужно будет графику. Получил ошибку, приведенную на фото в первом посте данной теме. Поиск в Гугл дал, что нужно в *Настроить>Система>Процессор* поставить галочку в *Включить PAE/NX*. Включил. В результате установка как бы начинается: сначала идет поиск файлов на флешке, при этом флешка мигает, появляется экран с синим окном, потом, бах, в виртуалке цифры замелькали, замелькали и появляется вот такое сообщение: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] Поиск в Инете дал, что нужно в БИОСЕ в параметре, где есть Virtualizition что-то там установить значение Enabled. Я покопался в биосе, вроде, нашел нужный параметр, а его значение и установлено на Enabled. Что делать дальше, не знаю.